# $12$ Prisoner Hat Problem with $5$ different Hats

Tags: game-theory

There are $12$ prisoners named $A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K$ and $L$ and each of them was given a hat with the number $0,1,2,3$ or $4$ on it. They cannot see what is on their own hat but can see what is on the other $11$ prisoners' hats.

The guard calls them forward in alphabetical order and asks them to whisper in his ear what number they think is on their hat. If they are correct they are allowed to leave otherwise they get executed.

Before the prisoners are given hats they are allowed to devise an optimum strategy so that the most prisoners leave with their life. Once hats are given no communication is allowed between the prisoners (including any sort of secret code).

What is the optimum strategy and how many prisoners can survive?

Comment: Can prisoners see what happens to the prisoners before them?

Comment: I guess there is no information about the the number of 0s, 1s, 2s, 3s and 4s ?

Comment: I strongly doubt that  there is a strategy which will save *most* prisoners, that is, more than $6$. Perhaps you mean "the most" prisoners, as many as possible.

Comment: Prisoners can see if the person before leaves or is executed.

Comment: @Arthur: How would it help me to see what happens to the prisoners before me?

Comment: @TonyK Because that's the only way prisoners can send information about what they see to everyone else. It will not be foolproof, but if you see $A$ go free, you know he guessed right, which means that you know something about what he could see. I hope you can see that it _is_ a relevant point, although difficult to utilise well. It would've been much more relevant had there been only black and white hats.

Comment: @Arthur: yes, you are right. Thank you for enlightening me!

Comment: @Arthur, could you translate that "knowing something about what he could see" in terms of calculation.

Comment: @satishramanathan For a very simple example, say A agreed to say the number he saw the fewest of,  and then the prison guard happened to give out hats labeled 1 to A, H, I, J, K and L, and hats labeled 2 to the remaining six. In that case, A will see five 1's and six 2's, so he will guess 1, and be free.

Comment: (cont.) Now B could see six 1's and five 2's. But if he got to see A walk free, he knows that his own hat must be 1 or 2 (otherwise A would've seen one unique hat, guessed that, and been executed). He also knows that it can't be 1, because then A would've seen five 2's, guessed that and been executed. Therefore, thanks to being able to see what happened to A, he's able to deduce the number on his own hat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the OP's comments, later prisoners can observe the fate of earlier prisoners. But now it's easy to ensure that at least eight prisoners survive:

$A,B,C,$ and $D$ assume that the sum of all the hats modulo $5$ is equal to $0,1,2,$ and $3$ respectively, and base their answer on this assumption. As soon as one of them goes free, everybody else knows this sum, so they can answer correctly.

If none of them go free, the sum must be $4$. And of course if $A,B,$ or $C$ goes free, then $B,C,$ and/or $D$ are freed from their obligations, and will go free too. So the number of survivors can be anything from $8$ to $12$.

Comment: Damn I was always splitting them into groups. Congratulations this seems like a very good solution.

Comment: And how many prisoners at worst can survive if they all have to guess simultaneously ?

Answer (score 2):

I will post this solution supposing you meant that their strategy is deterministic.

Answer is $2$. To see that this can be obtained, divide $10$ of them in two groups of $5$ and ignore the rest two prisoners. To see that $1$ prisoner can survive out of $5$ take this strategy: first prisoner assumes sum of all their numbers $ = 0$ modulo $5$, second assumes it is $1$ modulo $5$, ..., fifth assumes it is $4$ modulo $5$. So each prisoner whispers a number that would make total sum of their hats one of the five possible residues modulo $5$. It is now clear that exactly one of them will survive.

To see that in general it's not possible that $3$ will survive, consider all $5^{12}$ possible distributions of hats. Try to count total number of correct guesses by all prisoners in all of those distributions. Examine $5$ distributions that differ only in first hat. Since prisoners play deterministic strategies, first prisoner will guess correctly exactly once in those $5$ distributions. Now divide all of the $5^{12}$ initial distributions into groups of $5$ groups of $5^{11}$ distributions that differ only in number written of first hat. It follows that in all $5^{12}$ distributions, first prisoner is going to guess correctly exactly $5^{11}$ times. Same holds for all the prisoners. So, in total there will be exactly $12 \cdot 5^{11}$ correct guesses. It follows that average number of correct guesses is $\frac{12 \cdot 5^{11}}{5^{12}} = 2.4$, so there must be some distribution of hats so that $2$ or less prisoners guess their hat number correctly, regardless of their strategy.

Comment: What colours are you talking about?

Comment: sorry, occasionally problems of this type are given in a way "prisoners are given hats of $N$ different colours" instead of "hats numbered $0$ to $N-1$", so I automatically wrote colour. I will edit my post.

Comment: A specific strategy to show two can survive is for each prisoner in a group of $5$ to assume that the sum of their numbers $\bmod 5$ is a different value and guess the number for their had that makes the sum that value.  You will save exactly one from each group of $5$.

Comment: I got told the answer was 3 or greater, I haven't actually figured out a strategy myself that can give 3 survivors guaranteed though.

Answer (score -1):

The probability of a prisoner guessing his hat number is $\frac{1}{5}$

The probability of a prisoner not guessing his hat number is $\frac{4}{5}$.

In other words, the prisoner knowing other prisoner's hat number has no bearing on his guessing his hat number correctly.  Each prisoner guesses independently of other prisoners.

P ( all guessed correctly) $={12\choose12} \frac{4^0}{5^{12}}$

P ( 11 guessed correctly) $={12\choose11} \frac{4^1}{5^{12}}$

...

P ( 0 guessed correctly) $={12\choose0} \frac{4^{12}}{5^{12}}$

This looks like binomial distribution and thus the expected number of prisoners who will survive $$\sum_{i=0}^{12} i{12\choose 12-i} \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^{12-i} \left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{i}$$

$$=\boxed{2.4}$$

Comment: You've computed the expected number who *don't* survive.  (I.e., your index $i$ corresponds to the number that guess *incorrectly*.)

Comment: Your strategy doesn't guarantee that anyone would survive. Everyone could guess wrong. You are looking for a strategy that guarantees the most survivors.

Comment: @BarryCipra, I have corrected it.  Thanks